# Can a union of convex sets be rewritten as a union of disjoint convex sets

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a compact subset of a finite dimensional Euclidean space. Can the union of finitely many convex sets in $C$ (possibly with nonempty intersection) be rewritten as the union of finitely many disjoint convex sets in $C$?

What if instead of "finitely many", we have "countably many"?

Thanks!

Comment: Your work so far?

Comment: I only have the conjecture. I tried several examples. For instance, if a ball intersects a cube at the corner, I can cut the ball using the affine hull of each face of the cube and get a positive answer. But more generally, how this can be done I don't have a clear idea.

Comment: Consider the convex hull of $(1,0,0)$ and an ellipse through $(-1,\pm1,0)$ and $(-1,0,\pm2)$, and the convex hull of $(-1,0,0)$ and an ellipse through $(1,\pm2,0)$ and $(1,0,\pm1)$.  I think the intersection of their boundary is winded enough to make finitely many disjoint convex swta unfwAIBLW ...